# Java Card Game: Deck Class help needed

Tags: java, arrays, oop, class, project

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so pardon me if I have a rookie mistake within my question and feel free to correct me as I plan to use this site a lot more over the next few months.

Anyhow, I'm a grade 12 Student at High School and am stuck on one of my homework questions.
So basically we've been given a project of creating a War Game (card game) and we've been asked to do small chunks of it everyday. So far everything has been going good until today, hence my question to y'all.

Here's what the project is about:

**Card**

- What it has:

  - Private int value: value of the card
  - Private char suit: suit of the card
  - Private Boolean drawn: whether or not the card has been drawn from the deck
- What it does:

  - Public Card(int val, char s): creates a card with value val, suit s, and sets drawn to False
  - Public int getValue(): returns the value of a card
  - Public char getSuit(): returns the suit of a card
  - Public Boolean isDrawn(): returns whether or not a card has been drawn
  - Public String toString(): returns the string describing the card in the form “value of suit”

**Deck**

- What it has:

  - Private char[] suits = { ‘c’, ‘d’, ‘h’, ‘s’}: representation of suits
  - Public int numCards: number of cards in the deck (traditionally 52 – make this lower for testing!)
  - Private Card[] deck: deck stored as an array of cards

---

I'm done everything upto this point.

- What it does:

  - Public Deck(): creates a deck of cards – values ranging from 2-14, one of each suit
  - Public card drawCard(): draws a random card from the deck that has not been drawn yet
  - Public String toString(): design however you want for testing purposes

Now I've finished doing the Public deck step with the help of Mr. Quynh below however I'm confused as to how I should go about creating the drawCard method. Here's what I have so far:

```
public Card drawnCard(){
        int randNum = (int) Math.random()*13+2;
    }
```

So i know that the above code creates a random Number between 2 and 14 but how do i use that to draw the physical card? Like what do I type so that the program knows to draw a card? Sorry, I know you may feel like I'm asking you for each step now, but I truly am lost and require your help!

I'm a newbie when it comes to programming and hence I apologize if this question is far too simple/noobie for you, but I really need your help :)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: No, the "above" is not correct. The instructions *specifically* tell you that you need an array of *Card*, not of int. I would start with following the instructions you've been given if I were you. They pretty much spell out your requirements.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your quick response and for making my post better :) I read over the instructions again but that didn't help me?  Last night's homework was the Card class, which pretty much has everything spelled out in the bullet points, but tonight's hw (deck class), I'm finding that a bit challenging, even after reading the instructions. This is my first programming course, so I'm not really quick at interpreting these things.

Comment: Oh so I changed it to public Deck(){
        Card[] deck = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};   
        
    } but now I'm getting a syntax error saying it found int, required card.newpackage.Card

Comment: Again, you need an array of Card, `Card[]`, not an array of int, `int[]`. The key to learning to code well is to write a *lot* of code and to experiment a *lot* with your code. Keep at it!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Apart from previous advices, I recommend you to read what others have previously done. There are several beginners examples (like [this one](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c5/s4.html)) which may give you another approach to solve your problem. Also it is a good idea to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for future questions. Good luck! ;)

Comment: Wow that link is mega helpful Mr. Rodas!! Thanks so much :) Also Thanks Mr. Hovercraft for your time and guiding me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starter, your Deck constructor should look something similar to this

```
for(int i = 2; i <= 14; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < suits.length; j++){
     Card card = new Card(i, suits[j]);
     card.isDrawn(false);
     //ADD CARD TO YOUR DECK HERE  
   }
}
```

As for drawCard function, just randomize a number from 1-52 (assuming you are using 52 cards deck) then draw it from your Deck and set `.isDrawn(true)`

Comment: A couple tips in addition to what Quynh said: Make sure that when you draw a card, you only return it if `.isDrawn()` is `false`. Also, what happens if all of the cards have been drawn when you call `.drawCard()`?

Comment: I would want to exit the game? Though I think my teacher wouldn't expect me to know that so hopefully she'll tell me how to do that on Monday. thanks for the code Mr. Quynh and Kevin :) I really appreciate your helpful tips.. Can't beleive it took you guys like 10 mins to answer this while I've been trying to figure this out for like an hour when my friend told me to post this question on this website.

Comment: ^Read on exception handling for the question Kelvin's asked.

Comment: @Quynh Could you please clarify as to how I should draw a card from the deck? I created a random number as you indicated, but I dont know how to make that into drawing a card? do I have to type out a ridiculuous if statement saying if teh random number is equal to 1 , then draw this card and so on until i reach the last number? That would take me hours

Comment: You know that you have an array of Card[52], and you can fetch the card from the card array by using an index. So, if your random number is 1 then you can get a card by card = Card[randomNumber].

Comment: @QuynhNguyen Hey, sorry to bother you again, I'm really close to finishing it, thanks so much for your help. This is what I have: 'public Card drawCard(){
        int randNum = (int) Math.random()*52+1;
        
        card = Card[randNum];
       
        
    }' But for some reason the card and Card[] are underlined in red saying it "cannot find symbol"

Comment: Did you instantiated your card variable? How does your Deck class know about the existent of your Card class?(hint: import) One last thing, what is the return type of your drawCard function?(hint: you are missing something in your function)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25056/discussion-between-ironman2295-and-quynh-nguyen)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
public class Deck {

    private Card[] cards = new Card[52];
    private int index = -1;

    public Deck() {
        // build deck
        for (int i=0; i<52; ++i) {
            if (i<13) cards[i] = new Card('s',i+2);
            else if (i<26) cards[i] = new Card('c',i-13+2);
            else if (i<39) cards[i] = new Card('d',i-26+2);
            else if (i<52) cards[i] = new Card('h',i-39+2);        
        }
        // shuffle deck
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cards));
    }

    public Card drawCard() {
        ++index;
        cards[index].drawn();            
        return cards[index];
    }
}

class Card {

    private char suit;
    private int value;
    private boolean drawn = false;

    Card(char s, int v) {
        suit = s;
        value = v;
    }

    void drawn() { drawn = true; }

    boolean isDrawn() { return drawn; }
}
```

Comment: I need help with the drawCard method specifically, I already did what mr. Quynh did above for creating the deck.

Answer (score -1):

You should use an array list for this to make shuffling easier. As this is homework I won't give you the exact code but,

```
ArrayList<Card> deck=new ArrayList<Card>();
        //add a loop with
        {
            Card card=new Card("initilize card here");
            deck.add(card);
        }
```

This should get you started and make it easier in the long run.

Comment: I want to use it, but I have yet to learn how array lists work, so my teacher woudln't accept something that I don't compeltely understand, however I do appreciate your help! :)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest anything outside the requirements for his assignment, despite the good use of ArrayLists. This project is emphasizing the use of arrays.